# Yii bootstrap widgets TbDatePicker not hiding after select a date

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

`Yii bootstrap widgets TbDatePicker` not hiding after select a date.

```
<?php
 echo $form->labelEx($modelRenterStatus,'moving_date');
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDatePicker', array(
        'model' => $modelRenterStatus,
        'attribute' => 'moving_date',
        'options' => array(
            'size' => '10',         // textField size
            'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
            'autoclose' => true,
        ),
    ));
?>
```

what's wrong with my this code?

Comment: what if you remove showAnim? The best you can do is check i firebug if there is any error

Comment: I checked in firebug,nothing there.

Comment: I would start by commenting out options and see if anything changes there. let me inspect the code deeper!

Comment: maybe conflict with `zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker`

Comment: I have always in past used both. let me check one project and update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [YB Docs](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms_inputs/view/datepicker.html) Options are

> options for the original library. This value will be JSON-encoded and
>   fed to bootstrap-datepicker

And looking into [library docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html) here I can't see the options you have put and so they are invalid.

Taking example from YB site

```
$this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbDatePicker',
    array(
    'name' => 'some_date_jap',
    'options' => array(
    'language' => 'ja'
    ))
 );
```

[language](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#language) is option  in original library. So recheck it again!

Just to expand my answer here is one that works with my form

```
<?php 
echo $form->datepickerRow($model, 'mode_attribute_here',array('hint'=>'',
                                            'prepend'=>'<i class="icon-calendar"></i>',
                                            'options'=>array('format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd' , 'weekStart'=> 1)
)); ?>
```

Comment: added example that you can use in your form

Answer (score 0):

maybe it help others!!
More detail [here](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/issues/436)

```
<?php
 echo $form->labelEx($modelRenterStatus,'moving_date');
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbDatePicker', array(
    'model' => $modelRenterStatus,
    'attribute' => 'moving_date',
    'options' => array(
        'size' => '10',         // textField size
        'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
        'autoclose' => true,
    ),
  ));
?>
```

Comment: so was you using outdated version or what? I cannot see difference from my answer!